In my code link.url is changing but pathName is not changing?
In my code link.url is changing but pathName is not changing. I wanted to give an animation transition to my website, but it is not supporting as the pathName and link.url are not matching.
"use client"

import Link from 'next/link'
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'

const Navlink = ({link}) => {

        const pathName = usePathname();
        console.log("link.url:", link.url);
        console.log("pathName:", pathName);

    return (
        <Link className={'rounded p-1 ${pathName === link.url && "bg-black text-white" }'} href={link.url}>
        {link.title}</Link>
    )
}

export default Navlink

giving this error
⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
link.url: /
pathName: /portfolio
link.url: about
pathName: /portfolio
link.url: portfolio
pathName: /portfolio
link.url: contact
pathName: /portfolio

I guess I'll get a good solution as I am expecting.

there seems to be a mistake where you’re using single quotes (') instead of backticks (``) for defining template literals.
Here’s the corrected version:

    {link.title}

With this correction, the class names will be properly interpolated, and the conditional class bg-black text-white will be applied when pathName === link.url.
<Link className={`rounded p-1 ${pathName === link.url && "bg-black text-white"}`} href={link.url}>
    {link.title}
</Link>

